# Display month as numbers instead of words

Tags: 16.04, date

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and I was wondering if there was a way I could get the default clock in the upper right to display the month as a number instead of as a word. For example, instead of "Tue Apr 25 2017", it would display "Tue 17/4/25" or "Tue 4/25/17".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `gsettings` in the following way. Open your terminal and type in the following commands as displayed below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-clock true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format custom
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "%a %m/%d/%y"
```

Result: `Tue 4/25/17`

Source:

[Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) you will can get other format strings that can also be used.

https://chrisjean.com/customize-ubuntu-unity-time-date-indicator/

Comment: Please note the update for the `day name` its `%a` not `%b` as earlier written...

Comment: Yeah, I'm working off the man page anyways. Thank you!